# Solving integral involving power, exponential and logarithm

Tags: integration

Any ideas on how to solve integrals of this type for some constants $a,b,c$, assuming the integral converges for certain values of these constants? I have tried everything from substitution to integration by parts. We can integrate this type without the $\ln(x)$, and the solutions usually involve the gamma function.

$$\int_{0}^{\infty}{x^{-b}}\ln (x)\exp\left({-cx^{a}}\right) \,dx$$

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Start by ignoring the $\log$ term. Make the substitution $u := cx^a$ to get the gamma function. Then differentiate with respect to $b$.

Comment: Are you familiar with the polygamma function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Substitute $u=cx^{\alpha}$, this gives you
$$ \begin{aligned} \int_0^{+\infty}\frac{\log x}{x^{\beta}}e^{-cx^{\alpha}}dx &= \frac{1}{\alpha^2c^{\frac{1-\beta}{\alpha}}}\int_0^{+\infty}\log(u/c)u^{\frac{1-\beta}{\alpha}-1}e^{-u}du \\
&= \frac{1}{\alpha^2c^{\frac{1-\beta}{\alpha}}}\int_0^{+\infty}\log(u)u^{\frac{1-\beta}{\alpha}-1}e^{-u}du-\log(c)\int_0^{+\infty}u^{\frac{1-\beta}{\alpha}-1}e^{-u}du \\
&= \frac{1}{\alpha^2c^{\frac{1-\beta}{\alpha}}}\left(-\alpha\frac{\partial}{\partial\beta}\Gamma\left(\frac{1-\beta}{\alpha}\right)-\log(c)\Gamma\left(\frac{1-\beta}{\alpha}\right)\right) \\
&= \frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{1-\beta}{\alpha}\right)}{\alpha^2c^{\frac{1-\beta}{\alpha}}}\left(\psi\left(\frac{1-\beta}{\alpha}\right)-\log(c)\right)
\end{aligned} $$
where $\psi$ is the [Digamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function). For instance,
$$ \int_0^{+\infty}\frac{\log x}{\sqrt{x}}e^{-2x}dx=\frac{\Gamma(1/2)}{\sqrt{2}}(\psi(1/2)-\log 2)=-\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}(\gamma+\log 8). $$